# Compare time and execute some a task repeatedly

Tags: java, date

I want to execute a task periodically if time is in between

```
9 AM to 9:11 AM
```

I was able to capture the current time, but could please tell me how can I compare that with the above condition ??

```
public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String systemTime = sdf.format(new Date()).toString();
        System.out.println(systemTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: u may try using [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)

Comment: use a Timer and check Time between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use while loop to achieve that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String systemTime = sdf.format(new Date()).toString();

    String START = "09:00:00";
    String END = "09:11:00";

    while (compareTime(systemTime, START, END))
    {
        System.out.println("Your task here");
        systemTime = sdf.format(new Date()).toString();
    }
}

private static boolean compareTime(String systemTime, String START, String END)
{
    return systemTime.compareTo(START) >= 0 && systemTime.compareTo(END) <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [quartz-scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation).

Example is given in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164401/1686291)

So if you want to run job between 9 AM to 9:11 AM every day, every year, every month. You can use following cron time notation.

```
//Create instance of factory
SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory=new StdSchedulerFactory();

//Get schedular
Scheduler scheduler= schedulerFactory.getScheduler();

//Create JobDetail object specifying which Job you want to execute
JobDetail jobDetail=new JobDetail("myTestClass","myTest",Test.class);

//Associate Trigger to the Job
CronTrigger trigger=new CronTrigger("cronTrigger","myTest","1-11 9 * * * *");

//Pass JobDetail and trigger dependencies to schedular
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger);

//Start schedular
scheduler.start();
```

Here, `MyTest` class will be executed at scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. This will give you hour and minute fields which you can compare.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: I see you're using "Code Sample" (Ctrl-K) for non-code in most of your answers, even after it's been corrected by others in your previous answers. When posting a post containing code, be sure to select **just** the code before pressing the "Code Sample" button or Ctrl-K.