# how to let a library know a non activity class?

Tags: java, android, dependencies, shared-libraries, static-methods

Maybe this answer exists but I couldn't find it here nor google.

I have a static singleton class named **Handler** (non activity class). I added a library to my project and I would like to use the Handler in **MainActivity** of the library.

```
-- app
    --java
        --com.mytest
            --Handler
-- library
    --java
        --com.mylib
            --MainActivity
```

I've tried to import com.mytest.Handler in MainActivity but it didn't work.
Maybe I should add some dependency to the library? I'm really lost.

**EDITED:**

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mButtonMoreApps = null;
    private ArrayList<String> mListUrl = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.mylib.R.layout.main_activity);

    }
}
```

mylib gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.20.0'
    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0') // app     invites
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Is your class com.mytest.Handler public?

Comment: yes. public class Handler

Comment: Can you add code (activity and gradle script)?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call application method from a library by importing to library.You can use listeners instead.

For an example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31626226/2176401

Library class corresponds to `Observable` class there and your application class should implement `Observer`. After that, you can use `notifyObservers` method to call the code you write in Handler class