# How to implement Java cron jobs with spring framework and is spring batch am i looking for?

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-batch, java-threads

Currently we are using `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`, `java.util.concurrent.Future`, `java.util.concurrent.Callable` to run cron jobs daily. Here our task is grabbing contacts from `Gmail java api`. We want to implement cron jobs with spring framework. please let me know how?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Java cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163662/how-to-create-a-java-cron-job)

Comment: Quatz with Spring is what you are looking for I guess. Refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/)

Comment: @Raman Shrivastava   but i am looking cron jobs with spring framework. thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running the process at scheduled time, you can use any of the expression (unix [cron expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) or fixed delay/rate) with spring framework's Scheduled annotation.

```
public class DemoScheduleCron
{
    @Scheduled(cron="*/10 * * * * ?")
    //@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    //@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("This method executs for every 10 seconds");
    }
}
```

To implement grabbing contacts from Gmail api, you can use spring Quartz / scheduler which is explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Small snippet of configuring concurrency from above docs:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutorExample" class="TaskExecutorExample">
    <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring batch + cron

please see the below link: 
[1]http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-and-spring-taskscheduler-example/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your answer with some context; link-only answers are hard to search. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer