# How make a job to determine date only once from Java

Tags: java, .net, cron, jobs

I have a Backend in Java. I want to create jobs that run only once on a certain date.
I have seen examples in .Net I do not know if in my Java backend it's possible?

This is .Net jobs https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

for example...

```
createJob(Date date) {
...
start(date) {
...
myMethod();
```

use

```
createJob(myDate); //30-05-2017 15:25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with its
[`schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method that accepts a **delay** parameter. That delay can be specified in different [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) amounts such nanoseconds, seconds, hours, etc.

The idea is to calculate difference between desired date of execution and current time in some time units (seconds for example).

Here is a snippet that should give you a clue (Java 8).

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Runnable jobToExecute = () -> System.out.println("Doing something on " + new Date());

        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
        ScheduledFuture future = executorService.schedule(jobToExecute, diffInSeconds(LocalDateTime.of(2017, 5, 30, 23, 54, 00)), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private static long diffInSeconds(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        return dateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) - LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
}
```

You can track the completion status of your job via the [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) object returned by the `ScheduledExecutorService::schedule` method.

Comment: Yes it's correct. 
But what I'm looking for is to keep the instance alive on my backend server. And well also that you can alter the date or maybe cancel.

Comment: @marlonpya The `ScheduledExecutorService::schedule` returns a [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html). You can use that object to check the status of your job.

Comment: if today i do on a ScheduledExecutorService. then mayben tomorrow i wanna cancel this scheduled or alter how get spesific object ?

Comment: @marlonpya Did you bother to look at the class doc for `ScheduledFuture` that I linked for you in previous comment?  Notice methods like `isDone`, `isCancelled`, `cancel`.  And read the [Oracle Tutorial on executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). And search Stack Overflow as these topics have been discussed many times already.

Comment: I think you can create some singleton class that will be a context to your ScheduledFuture object. Expose one method (schedule, for example), which will cancel current ScheduledFuture and create a new one based on provided date. But, you also need to think about fault-tolerance - what will happen if you JVM goes down? You could store scheduled date and status (cancelled, done, scheduled) in DB and when application starts it will fetch those values and create new ScheduledFuture for example (or do nothing).