# How do I run code at a set time every day in Java?

Tags: java

Currently working on an algorithm for something and I need to run code at the same time every day. I've tried creating a timer but I'm not really familiar with it and the most I was able to do was run code every x seconds. I know I could do every 86400 seconds but that seems like a janky solution at best and I feel like there is a better solution. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Much appreciated.

Comment: If converting to seconds or millliseconds is your only issue, use [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html).DAYS.toMillis(1) or [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).ofDays(1).toMillis()

Comment: Does it have to be in Java? Why not use cron (if you're on Linux) or Task Scheduler (if you're on Windows)?

Comment: You can use cronJobs to schedule jobs for a defined time. refer to this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163662/how-to-create-a-java-cron-job

Comment: Solution of same question follow link:  [Scheduler's details][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java

Answer (score -1):

Say if you want to run `yourTask()` at specific time (say 10:00), you could do as below:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(yourTask(), today.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS));
```

Comment: this doens't compile, you'd need to pass a `TimerTask` reference to `schedule()` but currently you're executing `yourTask()` directly

Comment: `Calendar` class was years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. `Timer` was years ago supplanted by `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: This works fine! Thanks so much. The comment above is correct yourTask() didn't work, I just defined the run() method in scheduler and it worked fine.

Answer (score -2):

There are different shedulers you can use. [Quartz](https://quartz-scheduler.org) is one of them for example