event some time now
So every day this function would be run only, for example. It'd be nice if i can pass arguments.

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164401/2310289

Re-opening this Question. The alleged original is about using UNIX cron tool. This Question is about Java. Furthermore, we have a spot-on Answer already posted.

The most easy way is to use @Scheduled.
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.time.Instant;

@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class Scheduler {
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 30 8 * * ?", zone = "UTC")
    public void eightAMRun() {
        System.out.println("Breakfast time - " + Instant.now());
    }
}

"0 30 8 * * ?" is a cron expression which represents "At 08:30:00am every day"
